# How to return the string equivalent of an enum value

Tags: java, arrays, enums, constructor, return

I'm trying to implement this enum into my program so that it will return the String equivalent of the enum value. So for example, if the value of dept = 3, then it will return Printed Books & eBooks.

This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to work because when I go to my program tester class and I try to add a new OrderItem it says that the constructor is undefined once I enter an integer from 0-5 for the Department part of the constructor.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

**The enum**

```
public enum Department {

ELECTRICAL(0), PHOTOGRAPHIC(1), COMPUTING(2), BOOKS(3), MUSIC(4), FASHION(5);

private int dNum;

private static String dept[] = { "Electrical & Electronics", "Cameras & Photography", "Laptops, Desktops & Consoles",
        "Printed Books & eBooks", "MP3 & CD Music", "Fashion & Accessories" };

private Department(int num) {
    dNum = num;
}

public String toString() {
    return dept[dNum];
}

}
```

**The program**

```
public class OrderItem {
private int itemCode;
private String itemName;
private String itemSupplier;
private double itemCost;
private Department dept;
private static int nextCode = 1;

public OrderItem(String itemName, String itemSupplier, double itemCost, Department dept) {
    setItemName(itemName);
    setItemSupplier(itemSupplier);
    setItemCost(itemCost);
    setDepartment(dept);
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    if (itemName != null) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    } else {
        if (this.itemName == null)
            // a default value
            this.itemName = "Unknown";
    }
}

public void setItemSupplier(String itemSupplier) {
    if (itemSupplier != null) {
        this.itemSupplier = itemSupplier;
    } else {
        if (this.itemSupplier == null)
            // a default value
            this.itemSupplier = "Unknown";
    }
}

public void setItemCost(double itemCost) {
    this.itemCost = itemCost;
}

public void setDepartment(Department dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}

public void setDepartment(int dept) {
    if (dept == 0)
        setDepartment(Department.ELECTRICAL);
    else if (dept == 1)
        setDepartment(Department.PHOTOGRAPHIC);
    else if (dept == 2)
        setDepartment(Department.COMPUTING);
    else if (dept == 3)
        setDepartment(Department.BOOKS);
    else if (dept == 4)
        setDepartment(Department.MUSIC);
    else if (dept == 5)
        setDepartment(Department.FASHION);
}

public String getItemName() {
    return this.itemName;
}

public String getItemSupplier() {
    return this.itemSupplier;
}

public double getItemCost() {
    return this.itemCost;
}

public String getDepartment() {
    return dept.toString();
}

public int useNextCode() {
    itemCode = nextCode;
    nextCode++;
    return itemCode;
}

public String getDetails() {
    String result = "Item name: " + getItemName() + "\n Supplier: " + getItemSupplier() + "\n Department: "
            + getDepartment() + "\n Cost: " + getItemCost();
    return result;
}

public String toString() {
    System.out.println("Item Code: " + useNextCode());
    return getDetails();
}

}
```

Comment: You should link those values to the enum itself, not to some other array

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] that demonstrates your problem succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass Integer (0-5) in your OrderItem Constructor. Instead you need to pass the desired enum. This should work fine.

```
    OrderItem oi =  new OrderItem("PenDrive","HP",300.0, Department.ELECTRICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the title question was how to return the String value for `enum`, the answer could be to refactor the `enum` to have `description` field instead of inner static array of strings, and add a method to retrieve `Department` by the ordinal value:

```java
public enum Department {

    ELECTRICAL("Electrical & Electronics"), 
    PHOTOGRAPHIC("Cameras & Photography"), 
    COMPUTING("Laptops, Desktops & Consoles"), 
    BOOKS("Printed Books & eBooks"), 
    MUSIC("MP3 & CD Music"), 
    FASHION("Fashion & Accessories");

    private String description;

    private Department(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public static Department byNum(int ordinal) {
        if (ordinal < ELECTRICAL.ordinal() || ordinal > FASHION.ordinal()) {
            return null; // or throw IllegalArgumentException
        }
        return Department.values()[ordinal];
    }
}
```

Then method `OrderItem::setDepartment(int dept)` may be changed like this (instead of multiple `if` statements):

```java
public static void setDepartment(int dept) {
    Optional.ofNullable(Department.byNum(dept))
            .ifPresent(OrderItem::setDepartment);
}
```